# Uint8Array objects - getting misplaced while merging

Tags: javascript, blob, wav

I'm trying merge a list of many `Audio` `BLOB` objects into a single `Audio` `BLOB`. Merging is done. But, `Audio BLOB` are misplaced in the output of the single `BLOB` while listening to the sound.

Example:

I have following `BLOBs`:

```
BLOB-1 (10KB)
BLOB-2 (10KB)
BLOB-3 (10KB)
BLOB-4 (10KB)
```

After merging and start listening to the single `Audio`, the above BLOBs have been merged as

```
BLOB-1 + BLOB-2 + BLOB-4 + BLOB-3
```

From the above, `BLOB-3 and BLOB-4` got misplaced. This misplacement happens at any order.

NOTE: I have more than `100 BLOBs` for merging.

I have written the following code in a JavaScript file `wav_merger.js`:

```
var _index;

function getBufferFromBlobs(blobArray) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var _arrBytes = [];
        var _promises = [];
        var _completedBlobObj = [];
        if (blobArray.length > 0) {
            $.each(blobArray, function (index, blobObj) {
                _index = index;
                var dfd = $.Deferred();
                readFileAsync(blobObj).then(function (blobObj) {
                    _completedBlobObj.push(blobObj);
                    //_arrBytes.push(byteArray);
                    dfd.resolve();
                });
                _promises.push(dfd);
            });

            $.when.apply($, _promises).done(function () {
                var _sortedBlobObjs = _completedBlobObj.sort(compare);
                $.each(_sortedBlobObjs, function (index, blobObj) {
                    _arrBytes.push(blobObj.buffer);
                });

                var _blob = combineWavsBuffers(_arrBytes);
                resolve(_blob);
            });
        }
    });
}

function readFileAsync(blobObj) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        var _blobObj = blobObj;
        reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
            _blobObj.buffer = reader.result;
            resolve(_blobObj);
        });

        reader.onerror = reject;

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blobObj.blob);
    })
}

function loadWav(blobArray) {
    return getBufferFromBlobs(blobArray);
    debugger;
    //    .then(function (bufferArray) {
    //    return combineWavsBuffers(bufferArray); //Combine original wav buffer and play
    //});
}

function combineWavsBuffers(bufferArray) {

    if (bufferArray.length > 0) {
        var _bufferLengths = bufferArray.map(buffer => buffer.byteLength);

        // Getting sum of numbers
        var _totalBufferLength = _bufferLengths.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);

        //Allocate the entire buffer size.
        var tmp = new Uint8Array(_totalBufferLength);

        //Get buffer1 audio data to create the new combined wav
        var audioData = getAudioData.WavHeader.readHeader(new DataView(bufferArray[0]));
        var _UbyteArray = [];
        $.each(bufferArray, function (index, buffer) {
            _UbyteArray.push(new Uint8Array(buffer));
        });

        var _bufferLength = 0;
        $.each(_UbyteArray, function (index, buffer) {
            //Combine array bytes of original wavs buffers.
            tmp.set(buffer, _bufferLength);
            _bufferLength += buffer.byteLength;
        });

        //Send combined buffer and send audio data to create the audio data of combined
        var arrBytesFinal = getWavBytes(tmp, {
            isFloat: false,       // floating point or 16-bit integer
            numChannels: audioData.channels,
            sampleRate: audioData.sampleRate,
        });

        //Create a Blob as Base64 Raw data with audio/wav type
        return new Blob([arrBytesFinal], { type: 'audio/wav; codecs=MS_PCM' });//
    }
    return null;
}


//Other functions //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Returns Uint8Array of WAV bytes
function getWavBytes(buffer, options) {
    const type = options.isFloat ? Float32Array : Uint16Array
    const numFrames = buffer.byteLength / type.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT

    const headerBytes = getWavHeader(Object.assign({}, options, { numFrames }))
    const wavBytes = new Uint8Array(headerBytes.length + buffer.byteLength);

    // prepend header, then add pcmBytes
    wavBytes.set(headerBytes, 0)
    wavBytes.set(new Uint8Array(buffer), headerBytes.length)

    return wavBytes
}

// adapted from https://gist.github.com/also/900023
// returns Uint8Array of WAV header bytes
function getWavHeader(options) {
    const numFrames = options.numFrames
    const numChannels = options.numChannels || 2
    const sampleRate = options.sampleRate || 44100
    const bytesPerSample = options.isFloat ? 4 : 2
    const format = options.isFloat ? 3 : 1

    const blockAlign = numChannels * bytesPerSample
    const byteRate = sampleRate * blockAlign
    const dataSize = numFrames * blockAlign

    const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44)
    const dv = new DataView(buffer)

    let p = 0

    function writeString(s) {
        for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            dv.setUint8(p + i, s.charCodeAt(i))
        }
        p += s.length
    }

    function writeUint32(d) {
        dv.setUint32(p, d, true)
        p += 4
    }

    function writeUint16(d) {
        dv.setUint16(p, d, true)
        p += 2
    }

    writeString('RIFF')              // ChunkID
    writeUint32(dataSize + 36)       // ChunkSize
    writeString('WAVE')              // Format
    writeString('fmt ')              // Subchunk1ID
    writeUint32(16)                  // Subchunk1Size
    writeUint16(format)              // AudioFormat
    writeUint16(numChannels)         // NumChannels
    writeUint32(sampleRate)          // SampleRate
    writeUint32(byteRate)            // ByteRate
    writeUint16(blockAlign)          // BlockAlign
    writeUint16(bytesPerSample * 8)  // BitsPerSample
    writeString('data')              // Subchunk2ID
    writeUint32(dataSize)            // Subchunk2Size

    return new Uint8Array(buffer)
}

function getAudioData() {


    function WavHeader() {
        this.dataOffset = 0;
        this.dataLen = 0;
        this.channels = 0;
        this.sampleRate = 0;
    }

    function fourccToInt(fourcc) {
        return fourcc.charCodeAt(0) << 24 | fourcc.charCodeAt(1) << 16 | fourcc.charCodeAt(2) << 8 | fourcc.charCodeAt(3);
    }

    WavHeader.RIFF = fourccToInt("RIFF");
    WavHeader.WAVE = fourccToInt("WAVE");
    WavHeader.fmt_ = fourccToInt("fmt ");
    WavHeader.data = fourccToInt("data");

    WavHeader.readHeader = function (dataView) {
        var w = new WavHeader();

        var header = dataView.getUint32(0, false);
        if (WavHeader.RIFF != header) {
            return;
        }
        var fileLen = dataView.getUint32(4, true);
        if (WavHeader.WAVE != dataView.getUint32(8, false)) {
            return;
        }
        if (WavHeader.fmt_ != dataView.getUint32(12, false)) {
            return;
        }
        var fmtLen = dataView.getUint32(16, true);
        var pos = 16 + 4;
        switch (fmtLen) {
            case 16:
            case 18:
                w.channels = dataView.getUint16(pos + 2, true);
                w.sampleRate = dataView.getUint32(pos + 4, true);
                break;
            default:
                throw 'extended fmt chunk not implemented';
        }
        pos += fmtLen;
        var data = WavHeader.data;
        var len = 0;
        while (data != header) {
            header = dataView.getUint32(pos, false);
            len = dataView.getUint32(pos + 4, true);
            if (data == header) {
                break;
            }
            pos += (len + 8);
        }
        w.dataLen = len;
        w.dataOffset = pos + 8;
        return w;
    };

    getAudioData.WavHeader = WavHeader;

}


function compare(a, b) {
    try {
        if (a.audio_recording_id < b.audio_recording_id) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a.audio_recording_id > b.audio_recording_id) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    } catch (e) {
        FDSCS.CORE.Logger.Log("compare()", e);
    }
}

getAudioData();
```

I'm suspecting at the `Uint8Array().set()` method. But, it can be any other issue also.

```
 var _bufferLength = 0;
        $.each(_UbyteArray, function (index, buffer) {
            //Combine array bytes of original wavs buffers.
            tmp.set(buffer, _bufferLength);
            _bufferLength += buffer.byteLength;
        });
```

I don't know what I have to do for this misplacement. How to fix this, so that, `Audio` will be played smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be due to this bit

```js
$.each(blobArray, function (index, blobObj) {
  _index = index;
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  readFileAsync(blobObj).then(function (blobObj) {
    _completedBlobObj.push(blobObj);
    //_arrBytes.push(byteArray);
    dfd.resolve();
  });
  _promises.push(dfd);
});
```

you are using `readFileAsync` which will read the files in parallel and the order that the files are read in (and the promises are resolved) is not guaranteed to resolve in the same order.

You could deal with it in two ways, either use a synchronous (blocking) process or you can store the index

```js
// use obj instead of array
_completedBlobObj = {};
///
$.each(blobArray, function (index, blobObj) {
  _index = index;
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  readFileAsync(blobObj).then(function (blobObj) {
    // use _index to store order
    _completedBlobObj[_index] = (blobObj);
    dfd.resolve();
  });
  _promises.push(dfd);
});
```